# How can I convert a f64 to f32 and get the closest approximation and the next greater or smaller value?

Tags: rust, floating-point

Possible pseudocode for the operation could be:

```rust
fn f32_greater(x: f64) -> f32 {
    let mut y = x as f32; //I get closest
    while f64::from(y) < x {
        y = nextafter(y, f32::INFINITY);
    }
    y
}

fn f32_smaller(x: f64) -> f32 {
    let mut y = x as f32; //I get closest
    while f64::from(y) > x {
        y = nextafter(y, f32::NEG_INFINITY);
    }
    y
}
```

I can not find an equivalent to C11's [`nextafter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) function in the libc crate or in [the methods on `f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html)

For context, I have an R-tree index using `f32`. I want to search the region with coordinates provided as a `f64`, so I need the smallest possible region in `f32` that includes the `f64` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function was [removed from the standard library](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27752). A solution could be to use [the float_extras crate](https://docs.rs/float_extras/0.1.6/float_extras/), but I don't really like the way of this crate so here my solution:

```rust
mod float {
    use libc::{c_double, c_float};
    use std::{f32, f64};

    #[link_name = "m"]
    extern "C" {
        pub fn nextafter(x: c_double, y: c_double) -> c_double;
        pub fn nextafterf(x: c_float, y: c_float) -> c_float;
    // long double nextafterl(long double x, long double y);

    // double nexttoward(double x, long double y);
    // float nexttowardf(float x, long double y);
    // long double nexttowardl(long double x, long double y);
    }

    pub trait NextAfter {
        fn next_after(self, y: Self) -> Self;
    }

    impl NextAfter for f32 {
        fn next_after(self, y: Self) -> Self {
            unsafe { nextafterf(self, y) }
        }
    }

    impl NextAfter for f64 {
        fn next_after(self, y: Self) -> Self {
            unsafe { nextafter(self, y) }
        }
    }

    pub trait Succ {
        fn succ(self) -> Self;
    }

    impl Succ for f32 {
        fn succ(self) -> Self {
            self.next_after(f32::INFINITY)
        }
    }

    impl Succ for f64 {
        fn succ(self) -> Self {
            self.next_after(f64::INFINITY)
        }
    }

    pub trait Pred {
        fn pred(self) -> Self;
    }
    impl Pred for f32 {
        fn pred(self) -> Self {
            self.next_after(f32::NEG_INFINITY)
        }
    }

    impl Pred for f64 {
        fn pred(self) -> Self {
            self.next_after(f64::NEG_INFINITY)
        }
    }

}

use crate::float::{Pred, Succ};
use num_traits::cast::{FromPrimitive, ToPrimitive};

fn f32_greater<T>(x: T) -> Option<f32>
where
    T: ToPrimitive + FromPrimitive + std::cmp::PartialOrd,
{
    let mut y = x.to_f32()?;
    while T::from_f32(y)? < x {
        y = y.succ();
    }
    Some(y)
}

fn f32_smaller<T>(x: T) -> Option<f32>
where
    T: ToPrimitive + FromPrimitive + std::cmp::PartialOrd,
{
    let mut y = x.to_f32()?;
    while T::from_f32(y)? > x {
        y = y.pred();
    }
    Some(y)
}

fn main() {
    let a = 42.4242424242424242;
    println!(
        "{:.16?} < {:.16} < {:.16?}",
        f32_smaller(a),
        a,
        f32_greater(a)
    );
}
```

I don't understand why they [don't include it in the num crate](https://github.com/rust-num/num/issues/118#issuecomment-496760667).