# Problem when write a set of general math tool functions for f64\f32\i32\i64 array

Tags: rust

Now I want to write a set of general math tool functions for f64\f32\i32\i64 array

Some functions are simple to write, such as addition functions：

```rust
pub fn add_val<T: std::ops::Add<Output=T> + Copy>(val1: &[T; 2], val2: &[T; 2]) -> [T; 2]{
    [val1[0] + val2[0], val1[1] + val2[1]]
}
```

But I have encountered some problems when implementing some functions. For example, there is a normalize function:

```
pub fn normalize(val: &[f64; 2], len: &f64) -> [f64; 2] {
  let real_length = (val[0] * val[0] + val[1] * val[1]).sqrt();
  if real_length == 0.0 { // fix: NaN when 0
    return [val[0], val[1]]
  } else {
    let scale = len / real_length;
    [val[0] * scale, val[1] * scale]
  }
}
```

it is easy to understand，Now I want it to support more data types.

One of my attempts：

```rust
pub fn normalize<T: std::ops::Add<Output=T> + std::ops::Mul<Output=T> + std::ops::Div<Output=T> + std::convert::From<f32> + std::convert::Into<f32> + Copy + std::cmp::PartialEq>(val: &[T; 2], len: &T) -> [T; 2] {
    let pow_num: f32 = (val[0] * val[0] + val[1] * val[1]).into();
    let real_length: f32 = (pow_num).sqrt();
    if real_length == 0.0 { // fix: 不特判 0 可能会返回 NaN
        return [val[0], val[1]]
    } else {
        let scale = *len / T::from(real_length);
        [val[0] * scale, val[1] * scale]
    }
}
```

This is an error :

```
58 |     let c = normalize(&a, &3.0);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<f64>` is not implemented for `f32`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <f32 as std::convert::From<i16>>
             <f32 as std::convert::From<i8>>
             <f32 as std::convert::From<u16>>
             <f32 as std::convert::From<u8>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on
```

The [reason](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-is-i32-from-f-not-allowed-but-f-as-i32-is/28151/4) for this error

I also try to use `as` But was told that as can only be used in the primitive type。

I found that Primitive trait [has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044026/what-happened-to-stdnumprimitive) so I don't know how to qualify...

If you have good ideas I hope you can share with me, thank you very much.

Comment: https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/cast/trait.ToPrimitive.html#method.to_f64, but note there is no good reason to do this, you should not mix float precision. You will run to unexpected result

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56348835/7076153

Comment: see: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62231